# How to display specific device via Bluetooth with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, display, scanning

I'm on creating a flutter application for communicating devices via bluetooth.

Actually, while scanning,I want just to display a specific device not all the devices.

This is the code of start scanning:

```
private ScanCallback getScanCallback21() {
    if (scanCallback21 == null) {
        scanCallback21 = new ScanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                    super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                    if (!allowDuplicates && result != null && result.getDevice() != null && result.getDevice().getAddress() != null) {
                        if (macDeviceScanned.contains(result.getDevice().getAddress())) return;
                        macDeviceScanned.add(result.getDevice().getAddress());
                    }
                    Protos.ScanResult scanResult = ProtoMaker.from(result.getDevice(), result);
                    invokeMethodUIThread("ScanResult", scanResult.toByteArray());
                }

                @Override
                public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
                    super.onBatchScanResults(results);

                }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display devices where `macAddress=="OO:FE"` for example.

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: try create of list of service id or remote id you wanted to to allow top show

Comment: @ArbiterChil how ! I didn't get it

Comment: Every BLE device have service uuid

Comment: @ArbiterChil the device that I want to connect with it contains 3 services

Comment: On what paackage you using? Flutter reactive ble? flutter blue plus?

Comment: @ArbiterChil flutter_blue

Comment: try flutter reactive ble since it have a set of list you wanted to display for ble use using the services id you had and wanted to find